# Random system freeze, vmware tainted modules

Tags: linux, fedora, kernel

Keep getting system freezes, no keyboard or mouse response, only reboot works.
*Problem Reporting* reports error:

```
A kernel problem occurred, but your kernel has been tainted (flags:GDOE). Explanation:
D - Kernel has oopsed before
O - Out-of-tree module has been loaded.
E - Unsigned module has been loaded.
Kernel maintainers are unable to diagnose tainted reports. Tainted modules: vmnet,vmmon.
```

Modules seem to be VMware related.

Output of `dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn` is:

```
ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
usb: port power management may be unreliable
i8042: Warning: Keylock active
systemd[1]: /usr/lib/systemd/system/plymouth-start.service:15: Unit configured to use KillMode=none. This is unsafe, as it disables systemd's process lifecycle management for the service. Please update your service to use a safer KillMode=, such as 'mixed' or 'control-group'. Support for KillMode=none is deprecated and will eventually be removed.
acpi PNP0C14:02: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:03: WQBC data block query control method not found
acpi PNP0C14:03: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
acpi PNP0C14:04: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
acpi PNP0C14:05: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
acpi PNP0C14:06: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
acpi PNP0C14:07: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
i2c_hid i2c-DELL09A1:00: supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator
i2c_hid i2c-DELL09A1:00: supply vddl not found, using dummy regulator
systemd-sysv-generator[517]: SysV service '/etc/rc.d/init.d/livesys' lacks a native systemd unit file. Automatically generating a unit file for compatibility. Please update package to include a native systemd unit file, in order to make it more safe and robust.
systemd-sysv-generator[517]: SysV service '/etc/rc.d/init.d/livesys-late' lacks a native systemd unit file. Automatically generating a unit file for compatibility. Please update package to include a native systemd unit file, in order to make it more safe and robust.
systemd-sysv-generator[517]: SysV service '/etc/rc.d/init.d/vmware-USBArbitrator' lacks a native systemd unit file. Automatically generating a unit file for compatibility. Please update package to include a native systemd unit file, in order to make it more safe and robust.
systemd-sysv-generator[517]: SysV service '/etc/rc.d/init.d/vmware' lacks a native systemd unit file. Automatically generating a unit file for compatibility. Please update package to include a native systemd unit file, in order to make it more safe and robust.
systemd[1]: /usr/lib/systemd/system/plymouth-start.service:15: Unit configured to use KillMode=none. This is unsafe, as it disables systemd's process lifecycle management for the service. Please update your service to use a safer KillMode=, such as 'mixed' or 'control-group'. Support for KillMode=none is deprecated and will eventually be removed.
platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-56.ucode failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Accelerometer lis3lv02d is present on SMBus but its address is unknown, skipping registration
thermal thermal_zone8: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
vmmon: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
bridge-wlo1: interface wlo1 unregistered without going down! Disabling the bridge
```

Using latest kernel `5.9.16-200.fc33.x86_64`, Fedora 33 KDE Plasma on a Dell Latitude 5510 laptop. Just getting used to Linux, please let me know if more info is necessary and what else I can check to find what's causing the issue.

***UPDATE***

result of `journalctl -b-1 -g failed`, `journalctl -b-1 -g warn`, `journalctl -b-1 -g error`

```
rngd[238]: [hwrng ]: Initialization Failed
rngd[238]: [pkcs11]: Initialization Failed
rngd[238]: [rtlsdr]: Initialization Failed
kernel: i8042: Warning: Keylock active
kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: DPC: error containment capabilities: Int Msg #0, RPExt+ PoisonedTLP+ SwTrigger+ RP PIO Log 4, DL_ActiveErr+
kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: DPC: error containment capabilities: Int Msg #0, RPExt+ PoisonedTLP+ SwTrigger+ RP PIO Log 4, DL_ActiveErr+
kernel: RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
```

Some other highlighted entries in the log:

```
ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored

systemd[1]: /usr/lib/systemd/system/plymouth-start.service:15: Unit configured to use KillMode=none. This is unsafe, as it disables systemd's process lifecycle management for the service. Please update your service to use a safer KillMode=, such as 'mixed' or 'control-group'. Support for KillMode=none is deprecated and will eventually be removed.

kernel: acpi PNP0C14:02: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
kernel: wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:03: WQBC data block query control method not found
kernel: acpi PNP0C14:03: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
kernel: acpi PNP0C14:04: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
kernel: acpi PNP0C14:05: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
kernel: acpi PNP0C14:06: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
kernel: acpi PNP0C14:07: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
kernel: i2c_hid i2c-DELL09A1:00: supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator
kernel: i2c_hid i2c-DELL09A1:00: supply vddl not found, using dummy regulator
systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/teamviewerd.service:9: PIDFile= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/teamviewerd.pid → /run/teamviewerd.pid; please update the unit file accordingly.
systemd[1]: /usr/lib/systemd/system/smartd.service:10: Standard output type syslog is obsolete, automatically updating to journal. Please update your unit file, and consider removing the setting altogether.
systemd[1]: /usr/lib/systemd/system/mcelog.service:8: Standard output type syslog is obsolete, automatically updating to journal. Please update your unit file, and consider removing the setting altogether.
```

Comment: Do you need to use vmware? Fedora Workstation includes a native virtualization system — look at the "Boxes" app or "virt-manager" for a more advanced UI.

Comment: I used virtualbox but had the same issue with their modules so i tried vmware. I will look into "Boxes" or "virt-manager", but i was wondering if there is a known issue with virtualization using vmware or virtualbox that is causing these freezes or is something else wrong with my system. Thx for your input.

Comment: I removed vmware and now I am using virt-manager.Unfortunately still getting system freeze, but no errors occur in ‘Problem Reporting’.Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: after a freeze, if you reboot and run `journalctl -b-1` to see the log from the last boot, is there anything interesting?

Comment: I checked the boot log and filtered for some keywords.I updated the post with the results.

Comment: Is there anything else i can check?Keep getting freezes.

Comment: I installed CentOS and all the issues are gone.